# How to correctly model TypeScript's Partial<T> Type in Fable-F#?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I have following type defined in TypeScript:

```
type ComponentProps = Partial<{
  title: string;
  children: string[];
  classes: string[];

  // Maximum two status flags can be provided
  statusTypes: [int, int];
}>;
```

How do I correctly represent this `Partial<T>` type in F#? I know about `Option` type but some types are too large and using `Option` does not feel not very idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I correctly represent this Partial type in F#?

To my knowledge, there's no such thing in F#, and I'm not aware of any techniques to achieve something like this.

But for this particular case, Fable has the `Fable.Core.JsInterop.keyValueList` function, which creates objects from lists of discriminated unions:

```ml
type Prop =
    | Title of string
    | Children of ResizeArray<string>
    | Classes of ResizeArray<string>
    | StatusTypes of int * int

open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop


let props =
    [
        Title "The title"
    ]
let propsObj = keyValueList CaseRules.LowerFirst props
```